# How to insert raw json in Couchbase with the .NET client?

Tags: .net, couchbase

I'm working on a REST API for CRUD operations on Couchbase.

The Idea is to send directly to the backend the RAW Json coming from the request body.

There should be no serialization at all done by the Couchbase client.
You can actually get a document back from the store in a simple string (no deserialization).

As far as I can tell, this is not supported yet.

Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase will treat valid raw JSON strings as documents, so all you have to do is just send your string as the value and get it back the same way. Here is an example with the latest .NET SDK (2.1.1 at the moment):

```
string json = "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
bucket.Upsert<string>("my_id", json);

var op = bucket.Get<string>("my_id");
var str = op.Value;
Debug.Assert(string.Equals(json, str));
```

Looking in the Couchbase UI, we can see that our raw JSON string is a proper document:

[image]

Comment: I'm using the overload that takes an IDocument object and it seems it was going through serialization for the content. I'll need to double check.

Comment: The IDocument overload uses the default transcoder which, depending on the type of the value you pass to it either serializes it or converts it to a byte array. You can provide your own transcoder and serializer, but it's generally simpler to use the (key,value) overload like I posted above because you're not using any of the features of the IDocument interface in any case.

Comment: What about optimistic concurrency ?

Comment: The key/value methods also have an overload that takes a ulong cas as the third parameter.

Comment: This is indeed working, no serialization, checked with setting a TraceWriter in the serialization settings.

Comment: You might want to give the answer a +1 then. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can preform CRUD operations against Couchbase

**Example** from [Couchbase Documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/document/get---db---doc-/index.html)

The following example retrieves a document with the identifier beer_#17_Cream_Ale from a database named beer-db. Because the identifier contains a number sign (#) character, the identifier must be URL encoded in the URI.

Request

```
GET /beer-db/beer_%2317_Cream_Ale HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59840
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 259
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 21:12:28 GMT
Etag: "1-431506b53aeac96a225e619cfa7bb569"
Server: CouchbaseLite 1.486
{
  "category" : "North American Lager",
  "brewery" : "Big Ridge Brewing",
  "style" : "American-Style Lager",
  "updated" : "2010-07-22 20:00:20",
  "_id" : "beer_#17_Cream_Ale",
  "_rev" : "1-431506b53aeac96a225e619cfa7bb569",
  "name" : "#17 Cream Ale"
}
```

Comment: The original question was about using the .NET SDK, not the Couchbase Mobile sync gateway, which is what you're talking about.